# Pacing text after 'href'

Tags: python, html, innertext

[image]

I need to get text "Платонов А.П." Here's my code by far.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pip._internal.network.utils import HEADERS

URL = "https://www.moscowbooks.ru/books/?sortby=name&sortdown=false"
HEADERS = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15", "accept" : "*/*"}
HOST = "https://www.moscowbooks.ru"

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers = HEADERS, params = params)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    items = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "catalog__item")
    books = []
    for item in items:
        author_check = item.find("a", class_="author-name")
        if author_check:
            author = author_check.get_text()
        else:
            author_check = "Автор не указан"
        books.append({
            "title": item.find("div", class_ = "book-preview__title").get_text(strip=True),
            "author": author_check,
            "link": HOST + item.find("a", class_ = "book-preview__title-link").get("href"),
            "cost": item.find("div", class_="book-preview__price").get_text(strip=True),



        })
    print(books)
    print(len(books))

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print("Error")


parse()
```

I get problems with author, because it get like this:

```
<a class="author-name" href="/catalog/author/21381/">Платонов А. П. </a>
```

Also need a little help with price because sometimes it gets '2\xa0274' instead of '2 274'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you define `"author": author_check` in your dictionary, while `author_check = item.find("a", class_="author-name")` and `author = author_check.get_text()`. You can change your for loop into something like this

```
for item in items:
        author_check = item.find("a", class_="author-name")
        if author_check:
            author = author_check.text
        else:
            author = "Автор не указан"
```

For you issue with the display of the prices, you can just replace \xa0 with a comma or space.

```
"cost": item.find("div", class_="book-preview__price").get_text(strip=True).replace(u"\xa0", ",")
```

Comment: Everything worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've had to deal with similar problem. You can do the following:

```
author = author_check.get_text().split('>')[-2].split('<')[0]
```

You might have to substitute -2 with -1.